Are Tiagra BR-4600 brake pads compatible with 105 BR-5810 calipers?
Tiagra pads are about half the price of 105 pads. I wonder what is the difference and if they are compatible with the 105 brake calipers at all.

Which specific models do you have in mind? It is not even clear if rim brake or disc brake but please mention the specific models.

Rim brakes. I'll edit the question.

These are completely different, aren't they? In BR-5810 you only change the plastic part, the holder remains. In BR-4600 it is a whole disposable unit.

Better mention the specific pad types you are interested in, not just brake types. There are more pad types than brake types.  The pads like R55C4 can be bought with or without the cartridge. You can re-use the cartridge.

But I cannot answer whether you can use the single piece Tiagra pads instead of the cartridge type.

Looks like Tiagra doesn't have cartridge type pads. I got my answer by that. Thank you.

The pads used for these brakes are quite different. BR-4600 uses single piece brake blocks such as R50T while BR-5810 can use cartridge units like R55C. Both come in multiple versions for different kinds of rims.
While the blocks are complete disposable units, in the cartridge tap you can replace the actual rubber pad and the cartridge can remain.
Note that there are also alternative manufacturers of compatible brake pads with various quality and price levels.
